# Repunit Divisibility

Tags: modular-arithmetic, repunit-numbers

We shall define $R(k)$ to be a repunit of length $k$; for example, $R(6) = 111111$.

**Lemma:** Let $n$ be a positive integer and $GCD(10,n) = 1$. Then, there exists a $k$ such that $R(k) \equiv 0$ $ $ $ $ $mod$ $(n)$.

I 'm asking this question because I saw [this](http://projecteuler.net/problem=129) question.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the question though?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $k=\varphi(9n)$, where $\varphi$ is the Euler $\varphi$-function.

By [Euler's Theorem,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)  we have $10^{k}\equiv 1\pmod{9n}$.

It follows that $9n$ divides the number whose decimal expansion consists of $k$ $9$'s.

Thus $n$ divides the repunit $R(k)$.

**Another way:**  We can prove the result using  a great deal less machinery. For consider the repunits $R(1), R(2), R(3), R(4)$, and so on. For each repunit $R(j)$, *imagine* calculating the remainder when $R(j)$ is divided by $n$.

There are only $n$ conceivable remainders. It follows that there are repunits $R(i)$, $R(j)$, where $i\lt j$,  such that $R(i)$ and $R(j)$ have the **same** remainder on division by $n$.

It follows that $R(j)-R(i)$ is divisible by $n$. This difference is a repunit $R(k)$ multiplied by a power of $10$. But since $10$ and $n$ are relatively prime, we conclude  that $n$ divides $R(k)$.